# Creating IP aliases upon server reboot

Tags: ip, reboot, alias, rhel-6

I have a server running RHEL 6, and have created multiple IP aliases on it. However, when I restart the server, the IP aliases are gone.

I tried to edit the /etc/rc.d/rc.local file to include

```
ifconfig eth0:1 1.1.1.1
ifconfig eth0:2 2.2.2.2
```

But it didn't work.

How can I make sure that the IP aliases stay after reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use the standard process for setting up interface IP addresses.

Create a file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts called:

```
ifcfg-eth0:1
```

Containing:

```
NAME=""
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICE=eth0:1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONPARENT=yes
IPADDR=1.1.1.1
ONBOOT=yes
```

Chnage the netmask to reflect the one you need.